# 7C in cs circles- python Im not sure what is wrong with this yet

Tags: python, python-3.x

The aim of the code was to create a scalene triangle (with the number 1) with the sharpest point pointing downwards. The program works until you put a input of more than 17 by which point the program ceases to use purely 1s

I have looked into the program mathematically and cant see a fault

```
n=int(input()) 
X=0
for j in range(0,n):
   X = (X*10)+1
print(X)
for i in range(1,n):
    X = (X-1)/10
    print(int(X))
```

Can you help find why?

Comment: If you are starting off with python, you can do a whole lot of debugging yourself with vizualisations here http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=display Just paste your code and go ahead

Comment: It's a rounding issue: `input=18` leads to `(18-1)/10 => 1.7` which get rounded at `int(1.7)` to `2`

Comment: but then what about input of 21 leads to (21-1)/10 => 2

Comment: @BenHanley: ***"21 leads to (21-1)/10 => 2"***: Yes, you print `2`s, and so on bigger numbers you print `3`s, `4`s ...

Comment: It's a rounding issue, but not `(18-1)/10` as the first loop turns `X` into all 1's. That's clear with the first print statement which prints `n` ones. The rounding issue occurs when `X` is divided by 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the exact answer, but it's to do with float precision. When you do `X = (X-1)/10`, you're doing float division which, with larger numbers, does run into precision problems: see  https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html for more details.

You can get around this in your case by using integer division. If you replace `X = (X-1)/10` with `X = (X-1)//10`, you should get the behaviour you want.

Answer (score 0):

Python is converting the larger numbers to floating point for division, which starts to get small errors converting from binary to decimal with larger numbers. I found that if you change the assignment in the second loop to

```
    X = ((X-1)//10)
```

to do truncated division you will get the expected output.

It would be much easier just to use a string of 1's and convert to `int` later.

```
n=int(input()) 
for i in range(n, 0, -1):
    print(i * '1')

# if needed
result = int(n * '1')
```

Output (with input of 20)

```
11111111111111111111
1111111111111111111
111111111111111111
11111111111111111
1111111111111111
111111111111111
11111111111111
1111111111111
111111111111
11111111111
1111111111
111111111
11111111
1111111
111111
11111
1111
111
11
1
```

Comment: thanks for that answer but i'm intrigued as to why mine doesnt work

Comment: Yes I was just thinking about that. Give me a moment.